# jquery - How to make change margin-left of an element smoothly

Tags: jquery, css

I have a div and i want that if a person hovers on it, its margin-left will be 200px and 0px if the mouseleave happens. It works but i want it to happen smoothly so that it will complete in certain amount seconds. I am new to jQuery so how can I achieve this? Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css"><script src="jquery.js"></script></head>
<body>
    <div style="width:100px;height:100px;background:orange;margin-top:300px;border-radius:100%;"></div>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('div').mouseenter(function(){
            $(this).css("margin-left",200);
        });
        $('div').mouseleave(function(){
            $(this).css("margin-left",0);
        });
    });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Take a look at [$.animate( )](http://api.jquery.com/animate/). This effect can also be done much easier just using CSS.

Comment: can you please give me the syntax?

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('div').mouseenter(function(){
         $(this).animate({'margin-left': '200'}, 'slow');
        });
        $('div').mouseleave(function(){
         $(this).animate({'margin-left': '0'}, 'slow');
        });
    });
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4n8jjx0L/)

> The `.animate()` method allows us to create animation effects on any numeric CSS property. The only required parameter is a plain object of CSS properties. This object is similar to the one that can be sent to the `.css()` method, except that the range of properties is more restrictive.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it without jQuery, only with CSS:

```css
#box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
  transition: margin-left 300ms ease-in-out;
}

#box:hover {
  margin-left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div').mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).animate({"margin-left":200},1000);
    });
    $('div').mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).animate({"margin-left":0},1000);
    });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).animate({
      "margin-left": 200
    }, 1000);
  });
  $('div').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).animate({
      "margin-left": 0
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width:100px;height:100px;background:orange;margin-top:300px;border-radius:100%;">test</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('div').mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).animate({ marginLeft: '200px'}, 500);
    });
    $('div').mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).animate({ marginLeft: '0px'}, 500);
    });
});
```

The 500 represents the speed of the animation, indicating how smoothly the margin changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( "div" )
  .mouseover(function() {
    $(this).animate({'margin-left': '200'}, 500);
  })
  .mouseout(function() {
    $(this).animate({'margin-left': '0'}, 500);
  });
});
```

Comment: Worked perfecly. Thanks

Comment: Can you confirm answer? Thank you.

Comment: So sorry but I have too small reputation to do that.

Answer (score 0):

By using CSS3 transition property, we can move the element smoothly.

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/jsy59kmt/][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same using CSS3 On hover http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

Also if you need smooth transitions through jquery then you can try Jquery transformation or animations too.

Sample plugin http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/

Answer (score 0):

Check this 
https://jsfiddle.net/p16dLtpg/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('div').mouseenter(function(){
            $(this).animate({'margin-left':200},900);
        });
        $('div').mouseleave(function(){
            $(this).animate({'margin-left':0},900);
        });
    });
```

You have to use jquery animate